# How do your restart a buildkite agent

Tags: ubuntu, buildkite

What is the command to restart a buildkite agent?

Answer (score 3):

Restarting the Buildkite Agent on Ubuntu as configured by default should be:

```
sudo systemctl restart buildkite-agent
```

See the [documentation](https://buildkite.com/docs/agent/v3/ubuntu) for more info about the agent on Ubuntu.